# How to find images & javascripts of SandBox solution deployment?

Tags: deployment, sandbox-solution, solution-deployment

I have deployed SandBox Solution to my SharePoint Server.

After deployment When I open the site in browser, it displays the images of the Site but not working of JavaScript file. 
(I have given the complete path like http:\myServer\sites\MySite\MyModule\Images\abc.jpg and same way for JavaScript file).

When I try to find/locate the images & JS, I am not able to find the site directory in 14 hive folder.

Its working fine when I create Farm-Solution and deployed.

So How can I find these things for SandBox solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Sandboxed solutions do not deploy to the 14 hive. Artefacts deployed via modules are only accessible in the location in which they are deployed.

Verify you have the `Type=GhostableInLibrary` attribute on your modules, sometimes in Sandboxed solutions they can be hidden from the library.

Comment: You also can use SharePoint designer to find these files in the SharePoint site.